# How can I write on the toolbar in Visual C++ 6?

Tags: c++, visual-c++-6

I have a toolbar in my application and I want to write my current date on it. In the same height as all the icons of the toolbar are put.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This rather sounds like something you'd like to put on the status bar, not the toolbar. But in any case, you could add a static control to the toolbar and display the current date in that control.